# writeln() or writefln()?

Tags: d

Hello World for D looks like this:

```
import std.stdio;

void main(string[] args)
{
    writeln("Hello World, Reloaded");
}
```

from http://www.digitalmars.com/d/

But when I compile that with gdc-4.4.5 I get:

```
hello.d:5: Error: undefined identifier writeln, did you mean function writefln?
hello.d:5: Error: function expected before (), not __error of type _error_
```

Is this a D1/D2 thing? A library thing? It seems odd that writefln is a stdio library function and writeln is not.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, `writeln` is only available in D2's standard library.

Comment: And, as far as I can tell, gdc currently only supports D1—which explains why this is an issue.

Comment: Why do you think it only supports D1?

Comment: I suspect this bug is relevant
https://bitbucket.org/goshawk/gdc/issue/159/let-gdc-invoke-d1-or-d2

Comment: @Jonathan: My mistake. I was looking at the older gdc website, which hadn't been updated since 2007.

Answer (score 5):

As CyberShadow mentions, `writeln` is only in D2.  The difference between them is `writeln` just prints its arguments as-is, while `writefln` interprets its first argument as a format string, like C's `printf`.

Example:

```
import std.stdio;

void main() {
    // Prints "There have been 44 U.S. presidents."  Note that %s can be used
    // to print the default string representation for any type.
    writefln("There have been %s U.S. presidents.", 44);

    // Same thing
    writeln("There have been ", 44, " U.S. presidents.");
}
```